In ggplot2, I want additional numerical labels that are a math transform of the original. How can I do this in ggplot2?
In ggplot2, I want additional numerical labels that are a math transform of the original, and that appear next to the originals. How can I do this in ggplot2?
Here is a minimal example:
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
  geom_point()

and I would like it to look like Figure B . . .


You can use ggplot2::scale_y_continuous() and pass in a function to the labels arggument that transforms the break into a new label.
Per the documentation you'd want the last option:

labels
One of:

NULL for no labels

waiver() for the default labels computed by the transformation object

A character vector giving labels (must be same length as breaks)

An expression vector (must be the same length as breaks). See
?plotmath for details.

A function that takes the breaks as input and returns labels as
output. Also accepts rlang lambda function notation.



The rlang lambda function notation is written like a formula: ~ .x * y where .x is your break value and y would be the factor you want to transform that value by. Or you can use an R lambda like shown below.
ggplot2::ggplot(data = iris, ggplot2::aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  ggplot2::geom_point() +
  ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(labels = \(x) paste0(x, " (", x * 10, ")"))


Created on 2024-10-07 with reprex v2.1.1.9000

Yes. That works. Thanks. (I also found documentation n the 'scales' package that offers a different approach.)
